# How to calculate a trigonometric interpolation polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, interpolation

I have the following $2 \pi$-period function f:
$$ f(x) =
     \left \{
    \begin{array}{l l l}
        x: & 0 < x < 2 \pi
        \\
        \pi: & x = 0
    \end{array}
    \right.\\$$

I try to calculate the trigonometric polynomial $t_3(x)$ with supporting points $x_k = \frac{k \cdot \pi}{2}, \quad k=0,\dots, 3.$

Now i thought i have to use the discrete fourier-analysis.
But what exactly are my $y_j$, which i need to calculate the coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$?

I don't really understand how to calculate this. In university we just defined the Polynom in the complex numbers.

Thank you very very much, for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a *sawtooth wave*. You can easily find it on the internet (e.g. with Google), giving on top of the list: [Sawtooth wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) (Wikipedia), [Fourier Series--Sawtooth Wave](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html) (Wolfram MathWorld).